# Is it possible to use Android/iOS device as a bluetooth headset for another mobile phone?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm working on an application that will enable making and receiving calls via a connected Bluetooth device, similar to a car kit. I envision creating an app that allows both Android and iPhone devices to connect and utilize my mobile phone as a Hands-Free Unit (HFU). This means I want to make calls and receive calls from connected phones using my own device. How can I go about implementing this functionality?

I have read the Bluetooth documentation and also consulted GPT about it. Additionally, I have attempted to establish an RFCOMM channel between bonded devices using several UUIDs, but I have been unable to make any significant progress.

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS because apps don't have access to legacy bluetooth profiles

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.